# distinct values on meteor server side (on cursor)

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I'm struggling on trying to use distinct() in meteor. 
I've tried different packages, some of which were discontinued and, apparently from what I've googled so far, this is the one that should still work `monbro:mongodb-mapreduce-aggregation` but it doesn't work for me.

**How can I filter items on the server side filtering a cursor for repeated keys?**

I send a collection to the client of about 100 items, but within these items there are repeated keys. In the frontend I'm using underscore to make them unique.
The problem comes when I implement pagination. I'm listing 20 items at a time (5 per row) but when I show the first 20 collection items, it only shows 19 (because underscore is filtering one of them on the client side).
This doesn't look nice because there's one empty slot in the row that seems that is the end of the listing but actually if you click on "show more" pagination button, then I list 20 more items (but only showing 39, because one is being filtered).

`.distinct()` seemed like the perfect solution for me, but unfortunately I can't find a way to make it work...

How can I prevent this from happening without compromising the cursor sent to the frontend (and the performance)?

Comment: The [`.distinct()`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.1/api/Collection.html#distinct) method ( referencing the node driver doc's because that is what is being used ) does not return a "cursor" but an "array". If you need a "cursor" then you need `.aggregate()` on which you can apply `$skip` and `$limit` or other forms of pagination. So `.distinct()` is just simply going to return an array of **all** distinct items. No exceptions. Unless you provide a "range"  in the query of course, but that would be against the point of the list and pagination in the first place.

Comment: sorry @BlakesSeven, I don't think I understood, could you show me an example?

Comment: Your question is actually a bit vague. The only clear thing in there is you want "distinct" results and you possibly want to page them? I think you really should go an try `.aggregate()` yourself and make an attempt. Then people can help any problems you might have. You certain **do not** want `.distinct()` if you intend to "page".

Comment: I don't think it's vague. I'm already doing the pagination. But actually it doesn't matter if I'm doing pagination or not. I want to filter documents with repeated keys on the cursor. As I said, I can do it outside the cursor.